# How to move all text down without moving the borders

Tags: html, css

How do I move all the text and images slightly down to center them without moving the borders down with it?

I tried relative positioning each item but the border kept moving down and out of the height of parent container.

Here is the code (I am using an old page from the BBC website and trying to copy it to learn):

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Technology - BBC News </title>

        <style>

        body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        #topbar{
            width:1000px;
            height: 40px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: red;

        }


        #topbar-menu li {
            list-style-type: none;
            float:left;
            border-left: 1px solid grey;
            height: 40px;
            padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
            font-weight: bold;

        }




        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="topbar">

            <ul id="topbar-menu">
                <li><img src="images/bbc-logo.png"></li>
                <li id="signin-text">Sign in</li>
                <li><img src="images/bell.png"></li>
                <li>Sport</li>
                <li>Weather</li>
                <li>TV</li>
                <li>Radio</li>
                <li>CBBC</li>
                <li>More</li>
                <li> <input type="text" value ="Search"> </li>
            </ul>

        </div>










    </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the `line-height` attribute. For example, see screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Considering the browser compatibility, this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `<div id="topbar">` because your `ul` will serve as the container. From there, you can set that `ul` to be a flex container using the **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)** layout.

You should also reconsider using fixed sizes because they will only appear correctly on a fixed viewport size.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#topbar-menu {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
  background:red;
  text-align:center; 
  height: 3em; /* 300% of the inherited font size */
  min-width:900px; /* never less than 900px wide regardless of viewport width */
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;            
}

#topbar-menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 1em;  /* This is what makes the content vertically align */
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul id="topbar-menu">
  <li><img src="images/bbc-logo.png"></li>
  <li id="signin-text">Sign in</li>
  <li><img src="images/bell.png"></li>
  <li>Sport</li>
  <li>Weather</li>
  <li>TV</li>
  <li>Radio</li>
  <li>CBBC</li>
  <li>More</li>
  <li> <input type="text" value ="Search"> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I need to learn about quite a few things in here but this definitely pushed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will center align the contents vertically.

```
#topbar-menu li{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: nice idea with the `flex`.

Comment: The flex container should be the `ul`, not the `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try `line-height: 100%;`

This should let the text be vertically centered